# not able to load xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

please help me i trying to load xml file on my html DOM but i am not able to see it on my browser i am using windows localhost for this
getting error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null" in crome
and "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference" in IE

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

XML Flie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception, `xmlhttp.responseXML` contains `null`. That means that request was unsuccessful or response cannot be parsed as XML.
In order to make browser able to parse response as XML, server should apply `text/xml` Content-Type header. 
To be sure that issue is in headers try to use `overrideMimeType('text/xml')` to force parsing response as XML.

Change your code to:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its still not working i dont know whats going on

Comment: @SantoshVishwakarma - Could you try to catch the request for cd_catalog.xml in chrome dev tools and  add a screenshot to your question, it should looks like here http://1drv.ms/1FZyedU